# Interface builder does not support UIView sizes larger than 10000

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, interface-builder

I am building an application where I want to display a floor plan and the image is 10024x5404. As shown below, I set the view controller in Main.Storyboard to the correct width and height and received the following error: *Interface builder does not support UIView sizes larger than 10000*. How can I fix this error in the storyboard?

If possible, I would prefer to continue using storyboard instead of solving programmatically. It would be easier to do in the storyboard because I have a large number of buttons to add.

[image]

I tried changing the view controller simulated size from freeform back to fixed. My Scrollview and Imageview are still set to 10024x5404 but I can't see the entire image

[image]

Comment: Did you using with an scroll view ??

Comment: Yes I've added a scrollview as well with the same dimensions. I get the same error twice.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 11? If so, you can scroll the content while working in Storyboard / Interface Builder. No need to try and set your view controller's size like that.

Comment: I am using Xcode 11. I tried changing the view controller simulated size from freeform back to fixed. My Scrollview and Imageview are still set to 10024x5404 but I can't see the entire image.